# DKIM result: fail - wrong body hash

Tags: centos, postfix-mta, dkim

CentOS 6, Postfix, OpenDKIM

Have correct DNS records

Sending email using PHP mail() to appmaildev.com - returns auth-report:

SPF result: Pass

DKIM result: fail (wrong body hash: MpaYoPlKy8H4qX8syH3dOM1gPr6spBK5/INxl2X2uNs=)

Tried different solutions - no result

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There are several causes for these two errors: the message may have been modified (perhaps by a mailing list or forwarder) in transit; the signature or hash values may have been calculated or applied incorrectly by the signer; the wrong public key value may have been published in DNS; or the message may have been spoofed by an entity not in possession of the private key needed to calculate a correct signature.

Any way you can check your DKIM entry for your MAIL-FROM domain [here](http://dkimcore.org/tools/)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older post but, I ran into this issue yesterday. If you are using MailScanner for anti-spam efforts, try disabling the watermarking feature. I found the added watermark headers were invalidating DKIM hashes. Disabling the watermarks allowed the DKIM hashes to be valid. Yahoo was bouncing mail due to this.

Answer (score 0):

As the above poster mentioned, I also had this problem. We use a windows server as our mailserver and we have antivirus installed on it.

It was setup to scan each outgoing message, but this changed the hash / body of each mail, thus failing the DKIM check.

So if you have this wrong body hash error, make sure you don't scan outgoing mails :)